# Redirect back to the same position in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

How can i redirect back to the same position an element was? I have a favorite button and when clicked i want it to redirect back to where it was originally. Right now it redirects to the top of the page.

I have tried to use this solution `return redirect(url()->previous().'#something');` But this redirect back to the bottom of the page

Comment: Have you considered using Ajax?

Comment: No i haven't considered it.

Comment: Is `#something` the ID of any anchor tag?

Comment: Yes it is the name of a tag.  `<a name="something" /a>`

Comment: @user11710915 Make it `id` as well and see.

Comment: @vivek_23 with `id` still scrolls to the bottom

Comment: @user11710915 Ahh! My bad. It was indeed just `name` itself. Make sure HTML tags are properly opened and closed, like `<a name="something">Something</a>`. Could share the HTML or produce a minimum verifiable example?

Comment: @user11710915 This works for me targeting the scroll till the anchor tag https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9L5VMPD75WX

Comment: `<a id="something"   href="{{route('product.like', [$product->id])}}" >like</a>` @vivek_23

Comment: @user11710915 Add the name as well as you did before.

Comment: @vivek_23 thanks for the suggestion but it still scrolls to the bottom.

Comment: @user11710915 I can't help further without reproducing your issue at my end. Show the actual URL string and the complete anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try in controller

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors(['msg','Error']);
```

Inside your blade file

```
@if($errors->any())
 <h5>{{$errors->first()}}</h5>
@endif
```